# When all extroverts are gone

Tags: society, viruses

Mr. Hennahito has been living his life as an introverted person. He is happy with that, yet the environment he is living in is an extrovert biased one, and thus he was bullied for being "different".

What most didn't know is that Hennahito is actually a mad scientist. He has a secret laboratory under his house where he do experiments to make the world a better place (he believes so). He's been experimenting on a virus that would alter the part of the gene that makes people extroverted and turn that into introverted. Good news is, (or bad news) he finally succeeded in making one. After a proper testing that there absolutely no side effect or any other effect of the said virus, he decided to do world travel and spread the virus. By his approximation, in 15-20 years all extroverts will be gone.

Assuming that things will go as he planned, how the world will be in that 15-20 years when all extroverts are gone?

Comment: A similar idea is a major part of the story arc of the hard-SF Beggars trilogy by Nancy Kress. In vol 2, a virus triggers neuropathways in babies making them inherently fearful of strangers. Not quite the same as introverted (I am one), but the lack of desire to socialize plays out the same. Worth a read if you're working on such a story.

Comment: Do you mean "extroverts are gone" or "everyone who socializes becomes a hermit?" I'm introverted but still spend plenty of time around other people.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think enderland has a key question.  The line between introverted and extroverted is decidedly blurry.  Some examples of where you think the line should be drawn in your sci-fi story may help.

Comment: On last test I scored 54% extrovert, 46% introvert. I wonder what does it makes me. A virus victim? A change to 54% introvert? Or 100%? Or what?

Comment: @Mołot I think that makes you a human. :)

Comment: @PipperChip I'm on my phone now and I hit enter by accident. See full comment after I added missing part

Comment: You are making the same mistake many people make- the difference between intro and extro is *not* whether you like to socialize with other people or how skilled you are at socializing, but whether that socialization gives you energy or takes it away from you.  In Hennahito's world, there will still be parties, and games, and team-building exercises in the work place.  There will still be clubs full of people with the same hobbies.  Young men will still awkwardly ask young ladies out on dates.  All these people will just go home earlier and sleep more afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Venturing a guess, I'd say the world would be mostly the same except people would work shorter hours and the concept of "alone time" would be much, much more acceptable.

Introverts can do all the things extroverts do (and the other way around), it just costs them a lot of energy to do so. They would still need to do all the stuff that needs to be done, so at the core it's just a matter of working in shorter bursts and taking more time to recover.